# Comparison with multiple Where clause in LINQ C#

Tags: c#

I have two DataTables:

```
DataTable dtCatalogFromMySql;
DataTable dtDataForExistingProducts;
```

**dtCatalogFromMySql**

```
Id | productname  | barcode  | pricesell| type  
---+--------------+----------+----------+------
1  | Abz          | 123      | 2.01     | RS // different product name
2  | Abd          | 122      | 8.90     | RS // different price
3  | Abx          | 125      | 21.00    | WS  // both different
4  | Abf          | 124      | 2.11     | RS
5  | Abg          | 126      | 8.01     | WS 
6  | Abh          | 127      | 60.23    | RS
7  | Abi          | 128      | 9.10     | RS
```

**dtDataForExistingProducts**

```
Id | productname  | barcode  | pricesell| type  
---+--------------+----------+----------+------
1  | Abc          | 123      | 2.01     | RS
2  | Abd          | 122      | 3.90     | RS
3  | Abe          | 125      | 23.00    | WS 
4  | Abf          | 124      | 2.11     | RS
5  | Abg          | 126      | 8.01     | WS 
6  | Abh          | 127      | 60.23    | RS
7  | Abi          | 128      | 9.10     | RS
```

I need return only rows which are different as in first table

I need select all data where `Prod_No` **equals** to `baracode` and `Descript` **not equals** to `productname` and `Retail_PRC` also **not equals** to `pricesell`.

I am not getting results with this code

```
List<DataRow> matchingRows = dtCatalogFromMySql.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(a => dtDataForExistingProducts.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(b => b.Field<string>("Prod_No"))  
        .Contains(a.Field<string>("barcode")))
    .Where(a => !dtDataForExistingProducts.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(b => b.Field<string>("Descript"))
        .Equals(a.Field<string>("productname")))
    .Where(a => !dtDataForExistingProducts.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(b => b.Field<decimal>("Retail_PRC"))
        .Equals(Convert.ToDecimal(a.Field<double>("pricesell"))))
    .ToList();
```

I suppose, `Contains()` will also fetch the data if `barcode = 123456` and `Prod_No = 1234`, it is right? If I am right what is right way to compare string exactly same

Comment: Have you considered writing it as a query? 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

Comment: `Select().Equals()` is not doing what you think it's doing.  That's pretty much guaranteed to always be false. Are you sure you didn't want `Contains` for those as well?

Comment: @juharr not (!) is placed in the beginning

Comment: @Mangrio I'm only talking about the result of the `Equals` call, but yes that means your `Where` calls are just going to always be `true`.

Comment: will Contains give me the Exact comparison for string as I have already asked in question

Comment: @Mangrio I don't know what you mean by exact.  You're comparing one value with many.  Do you want the single value to not be present in any of the multiple values or just not present in at least one?

Comment: I mean that Contains() also make true this `bag 251` to `251 bag`

Comment: I think the best way for you to describe your desired results would be with example data for the two tables and the results you want and the results you currently get.

Comment: I am adding example

Comment: @juharr please review the updated question

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider a clearer syntax such as:

```
var results = from t1 in dtCatalogFromMySql.AsEnumerable()
              join t2 in dtDataForExistingProducts.AsEnumerable() on 
                  (string)t1["barcode"] equals (string)t2["Prod_No"]
              where (string)t1["productname"] != (string)t2["descript"] &&
                    Convert.ToDecimal((double)t1["pricesell"]) != 
                    (decimal)t2["Retail_PRC"]
              select t2;
```

The Join is definitely the way to go.  You can modify the select according to your required result set.

trighati makes a good point about using `OR` instead of `AND`.  This is assuming that you want all of the data where at least one of your values changed where Prod_no and barcode are equal.  This would change the query to be:

```
var results = from t1 in dtCatalogFromMySql.AsEnumerable()
              join t2 in dtDataForExistingProducts.AsEnumerable() on
                  (string)t1["barcode"] equals (string)t2["Prod_No"]
              where (string)t1["productname"] != (string)t2["descript"] ||
                    Convert.ToDecimal((double)t1["pricesell"]) != 
                    (decimal)t2["Retail_PRC"]
              select t2;
```

Comment: the condition will be `OR` not `AND`

Comment: True, that's probably what is really wanted, but I used "and" based on the initial description of the problem given in the question.
"I need select all data where Prod_No equals to baracode and Descript not equals to productname and Retail_PRC also not equals to pricesell."

Answer (score 0):

Use `Join` to combine them into one result set, then filter the result set:

```
var combined = dtDataForExistingProducts.AsEnumerable()
    .Join(dtCatalogFromMySql.AsEnumerable(), 
        ep => ep.Field<string>("Prod_No")
        ce => ce.Field<string>("barcode"), 
        (ep, ce) => new {ExistingProduct = ep, CatalogEntry = ce})
    .Where(m => !m.ExistingProduct.Field("Descript")
        .Equals(m.CatalogEntry.Field("productname")))
    .Where(m => decimal.Parse(m.ExistingProduct.Field("Retail_PRC").ToString()) 
        != decimal.Parse(m.CatalogEntry.Field("pricesell").ToString()))
    .ToList()
;
```

Comment: wil this return in DataRow list

Comment: Nope. It returns a list of anonymous objects, each containing two `DataRow`s. You can select either property into a list: `combined.Select(c => c.ExistingProduct).ToList()`